# Offset MySQL Without Limit

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql Offset Infinite rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Is it possible to specify a query in MySQL with a 'offset' but without a 'limit'. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM countries OFFSET 2
```

Fails, but:

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES LIMIT 8 OFFSET 2
```

Works fine. I'd like to just specify the offset. Thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Basically, no. Limit must be supplied.  [See this SO question for a solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Comment: please link directly to the solution