# Mysql select rows except first row

Tags: mysql, select

I have issue there with select from table. I want to select all rows except for first row. So .. There is my code

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

So this code select and order id's from table which give me id feedback "5>4>3>2>1". And there is issue .. How I can select and echo just 4>3>2>1 rows. 
So if I had rows with id's 1,2,6,8,10 , echo will be 10,8,6,2,1 and I want select to echo just 8,6,2,1.

There is my full wrong code for select.

```
$other = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, row_number()
    OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) row
    FROM table
)
WHERE row != 1
```

It gives numbers to your selected rows and takes all of them without the one with row number 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> $other = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 1");

**THE ABOVE QUERY WONT WORK AS A LIMIT IS NEEDED**

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271650/2187103)

Comment: Invalid MYSQL syntax, you can't use "offset" without "limit"

Answer (score 0):

All you need is offset 1, but offset cannot be used without limit. So, I'd suggest something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 99999999 OFFSET 1
```

Warning: make sure your table doesn't contain lots of records, otherwise you will run into performance issues. Or, change the limit to something reasonable, like 10.

**EDIT:**

Read: [How to use offset without limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173635/offset-mysql-without-limit)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id 
                      FROM table 
                      ORDER BY id DESC 
                      LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

You can try this.
In this case I am selecting all the rows, except the one with the biggest id.
In the example of [1,2,3,4,5], it will be :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE id NOT IN ( 5 )
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer but it sended me feedback " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC LIMIT 1 ) ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1 " ..

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed it.

Comment: Specifying the record id is not good as MySQL ids will be changing always. and here we need to skip the last record regardless of the id.