# MySQL LIMIT/OFFSET: get all records except the first X

Tags: mysql, limit

I want to query all records from number 50 and up. So instead of doing something like `LIMIT 49, 99999` I want to know if there is an official way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql Offset Infinite rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Comment: for this u can give condition by the primary key of that table know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, sorry. From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain
>   offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for
>   the second parameter. This statement
>   retrieves all rows from the 96th row
>   to the last:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But may I ask why you edited my first post? Is it forbidden to say hi and thanks?

Comment: No, it's not forbidden at all, but the title was rather vague, so I was going to edit it - and the hi/thanks don't add any useful content here for the future visitors on Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @Konerak: actually, I care about "Hi" and "Thanks". Being polite always help in getting an answer.

Comment: @Johann: There has been quite a conversation on meta about this, see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) - I tend to agree hi-thx-bye is just clutter. I won't edit a question that cannot be improved otherwise just to remove them, but while I'm improving, I'll improve the language and remove the clutter.

Comment: @priktop: [You're not a noob, more a newb](http://www.cad-comic.com/cad/20060823) - I hope ;)

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I'm using Microsoft SQL Mgmt Studio, ver 17.9.1.  When I try to use the LIMIT like show here, I get