# Select from nth record and so on in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL LIMIT/OFFSET: get all records except the first X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619167/mysql-limit-offset-get-all-records-except-the-first-x)

Ok I do have a sql query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `profile_registry` LIMIT 3, 100
```

now what i want here is to get data starting from the 3rd row and so on.

The code above works but the problem is the `LIMIT` can be used by using one or two parameters.

the condition of the only one parameter is it only controls how many rows to return.

the condition of the two parameters is the first parameter defines the starting point and the second parameter defines how many records to return.

Now my problem here is I can't set the second parameter as if its only 100 as we don't know how many records will be in the future. What **I want is to return all the records starting on a certain row without setting a limit on how many rows to return**.

Comment: @aleroot sorry I was trying to look for any existing answer in SO but existing question's title is quite obscure for mysql newbies.. I know this would help for the newbies in the future, pleae don't close it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result
>   set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This
>   statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;
> ```

Comment: limit 2, 12938129038290093 works ok try it

Comment: +1, I had an answer started with another way of doing it, but yours is better :-)

Comment: Answer copied from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619167/mysql-limit-offset-get-all-records-except-the-first-x

Comment: can I just put 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999? =)

Comment: @aleroot Actually no, I didn't see that question; I copied the answer from the page I linked to. But it definitely is a duplicate - good find.

Comment: well its really a duplicate but the title somewhat hazy for mysql newbies =)

Comment: @Mahan I don't know if it'll like a number that big, but you can try it :)

Comment: @Mahan Agreed. I actually like your title better. I would not think of expressing it as "except the first N rows" either.

Comment: well i really don't know why people are voting to make my question be closed.. :(

Comment: @Mahan It technically is a duplicate ("covers exactly the same content"). Although I prefer your wording.