# Return records from first record to get the number of records needed to return

Tags: mysql

Ok I really don't know how to explain this even in the title but this is what I want.

first I do have 5 records

```
id | name  |
------------
1  | ringo |
------------
2  | nashi |
------------
3  | momo  |
------------
4  | manga |
------------
5  | tokyo |
```

now I produce a random number on what row I will start querying. For example I got a random number of 4 and so I will get rows 4 and 5. But my problem is I need 4 records on every query. So it means I will go back to the first record and get the first two rows.

**Is there any possible way that I can go back on the first row if my query results lacks the number of records I want?**

This is a connected question [Select from nth record and so on in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740714/select-from-nth-record-and-so-on-in-mysql) that shows what I have done so far.

Comment: Write a query and find out how many rows you get. and then query again with LIMIT clause and have single parameter.

Comment: is there any one liner sql for this?

Comment: I think you can easily solve the situation on php side.. If it is ok for you, tell me and I will write an answer.

Comment: I know to do this in PHP side, but what I really want is to make it on  all SQL codes...

Comment: Is the `id` column *guaranteed* to be sequentially numbered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sort the table first by records greater than the pivot `id`, then by `id`, you need only `LIMIT` the resultset to the first four records:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id >= 4 DESC, id LIMIT 4
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12ed5/1/0).

Comment: awesome query. never expected the query in one line

Comment: @NaveenBabu: one could make it even shorter (but slightly less clear) with `ORDER BY id<4,id`.

Comment: can I do it without referring to the ID?

Comment: @Mahan: Yes, but the complexity of the answer depends on how "random" the pivot must be.  If each record *must* have exactly the same probability of being the pivot and the `id` of records are not uniformly distributed (and one presumes that they may not be, given that they are not necessarily sequential), then one cannot pivot on a simple random number between the minimum and maximum `id` values; instead, one may need to perform an expensive random sort of the entire table to decide upon a record upon which to pivot.  Please clarify your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
WHERE `id` >= 3 /* 3 is some random number */
UNION
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
WHERE `id` < 5
LIMIT 4
```

**EDIT:** eggyal's question in his comment is something worth considering. My suggestion with that option considered is below.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table`
WHERE `id` >= 3 /* 3 is some random number */
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 4
) a
LIMIT 4
```