# 80 rows of data , first select 1-20 rows , second select 21-30 rows

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table containing rows with timestamped.

Normally if I want to get the latest 20 rows out according to the time. I use:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM comment 
    ORDER BY time DESC 
    LIMIT 20";
```

But now, I want to get the latest comments AFTER the latest 20 rows and `LIMIT` to 10. That means rows 21-30.(of course , everything is according to timestamp)

How can I do that using MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has a built-in offset that you can use with LIMIT:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10, 20";
```

Also, refer to this SO post: [MySQL LIMIT/OFFSET: get all records except the first X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619167/mysql-limit-offset-get-all-records-except-the-first-x)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 20, 10";
```

Comment: How is this different from gmartellino's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will select from 21 to 30 records

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20, 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a mixture of limits

```
$sql = "select * from (SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 30) as A order by time ASC limit 10";
```

The mysql built in offset method others have posted looks better though.

Answer (score -1):

There are two options:

- Get 30 rows and use PHP to split the result set into a group of 20
  and a group of 10.
- Send two queries, one for 20 and one for 10 rows.