# MySQL: how to select everything except first 10 records

Tags: mysql, database, limit

How can I select all records except first 10 records from MySQL table?

(I know that `limit 10,x` selects records from the 10th to x-th, but what should I use instead of x to select all remaining records?)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows ?

Comment: Or duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619167/mysql-limit-offset-get-all-records-except-the-first-x?lq=1 ?

Comment: Can't you just calculate X with the COUNT function?

Comment: @filipehd I tried x=COUNT(*), but it didn't work

Answer (score 7):

Use `OFFSET`. Then you can skip 10 records and select the remaining ones until the end.

Then your query should look like

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE (condition) LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: `OFFSET` is not a valid MySQL clause.

Comment: `OFFSET` *is* a valid mysql clause. The problem is that it must be after the `LIMIT` clause or it won't work. Check the docs : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @Tomas, yes it's valid as part of a `LIMIT`, but not on its own as the above answer was implying.

Comment: Edited. 18446744073709551615 is the number that I found is used in the documentation to get records until the last one.

Comment: Also, the same query can be done like this `LIMIT 10, 18446744073709551615`

Answer (score 0):

Better get used to [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) condition because you can use it also for pagination.

Comment: That's not what I asked for