# Rails: Query all but first record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How would I query all *except* the first record using ActiveRecord?

Something like...

```
Item.where(:widget_id => 123).all_but_first
```

I'm running Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
Item.where(:widget_id => 123).all[1..-1]
```

Comment: Without creating the ```all_but_first``` method (which would probably just be this exact code) I think this is the easiest and obvious way to handle it.

Comment: Note that this will return you an `Array` and not an `ActiveRecord_Relation`

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively you could use offset and limit with a very high limit.

```
Item.where(:widget_id => 123).limit(18446744073709551610).offset(1)
```

see [Mysql Offset Infinite rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows) for a discussion on this.

Comment: This worked for me without the limit. Using Rails 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but in case this is useful to someone:

- If you want an array back, I think [offset](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset) is your best option and most readable.
- If you want a relation back, you can do: `widget.items.where.not(id: widget.items.first.id)`.

That is assuming you don't care about the order. If you do, you should add that of course.

Answer (score 0):

With scopes this can now be answered exactly

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    scope all_but_first -> { all[1..-1] }
end
```

But I would advise making sure you know what you mean by 'all but first'. Do you mean the first created, the most recent, the lowest id? When you know that, you can then add the ordering into the scope  e.g.

```
scope :all_but_first, -> { order(created_at: :desc)[1..-1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick answer for those who have the same issue:

```
Item.where(widget_id: 123).offset(1)
```

Returns instance of `ActiveRecord_Relation` class, which is usefull. And you definitely want to be sure about the order of items:

```
Item.where(widget_id: 123).order(:id).offset(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding to Veraticus's answer, you can also include the way you want to order the items:

```
Item.where(:widget_id => 123).order('created_at DESC').all[1..-1]
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: put .order('created_at DESC') before the all