# Correct way to delete 'older' rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has a `TIME` field.

I want to keep only 5 newest rows.

Can I delete the old rows without using `SELECT`?

I think logic should be something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE row_num > 5 ORDER BY TIME
```

How can I implement this in MySQL whitout using `SELECT` to get list of `TIME` values?

Comment: your question is not clear. make it proper first.

Comment: Add `LIMIT 5, 999999` to this query. And also have `ORDER BY TIME DESC`, instead of `ASC` (default). [View similiar question with the same unelegant answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Comment: Since it is written all caps, is the word `TIME` referring to an actual column of your table -- or is it some kind of placeholder?

Comment: Could you have some columns with the same `time` value or is it `UNIQUE` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux it could repeat

Comment: The OP originally said "I have list of rows with some sort of time field".  I edited this down to "My table has a TIME field".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without proper `ORDER BY` clause, SQL result set have to be considered as *unordered*.

You have to provide a column to explicitly store your rows sequence numbers. This could be a time stamp or the auto_increment column of your table.

Please keep in mind you could have concurrent access to your table as well. What should be the expected behavior if someone else is inserting while you are deleting? As far as I can tell this could lead to situation where you keep only the "5 latest rows" + "those inserted on the other transaction".

---

If your have the `time` column for that purpose on your table and a `PRIMARY KEY` (or some other `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column) you could write:

```
DELETE tbl FROM tbl LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY tm DESC LIMIT 5) AS k
    ON (tbl.pk) = (k.pk)
    WHERE k.`time` IS NULL;
```

If you have composite primary key `(a,b)` You could write:

```
DELETE tbl FROM tbl LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY tm DESC LIMIT 5) AS k
    ON (tbl.a,tbl.b) = (k.a,k.b)
    WHERE k.tm IS NULL;
```

Comment: He has a time field already. I agree there's a potential race condition.

Comment: @Paul I'm not quite sure about that as is it spelled all caps like a reserved keyword...

Comment: Assuming time or TIME is a timestamp on each row, I'm  more concerned that the docs for MySQL DELETE have a bare number after LIMIT (e.g. LIMIT 3) and not a window (e.g. LIMIT 10,15).  So LIMIT 5,10000000000 might be invalid.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: He also specifically said he wanted to avoid SELECT clauses, but probably needs one.

Comment: It seems difficult to avoid both sub-select *and* (the rather inelegant) `LIMIT 5, biiiig_number`

Comment: I don't have a MySQL handy and was worried that LIMIT 5, big number might even be a syntax error, the docs only show LIMIT 5;

Comment: @Paul It was so inelegant that I didn't bother testing it. But you are right. `LIMIT 5,...` (*range limit*) is simply not allowed in `DELETE` query.

Comment: What if PK is from 2 or 3 fields?

Comment: @xander27 I have updated my answer (1) because MySQL does not support `LIMIT` for `IN` sub-queries (2) to show you how to deal with composite primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM TBL
  WHERE ROW_NUM = (SELECT ROW_NUM FROM TBL LIMIT 6, 99999)
  ORDER BY TIME DESC;
```

This will delete records from 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ....., 200005

Because **LIMIT** range starts here from 6 to 9999 records, means 200005

Comment: Are you sure that ROW_NUM of delete and select will represent same row?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the top 5 rows, use something like:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE  primary_key IN 
(SELECT primary_key FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5,1000000)
```

100000 can be a very large no

Comment: should you change '*' to 'primary_key' ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be an alternative:

```
DELETE FROM tbl 
WHERE  primary_key NOT IN (SELECT primary_key 
                           FROM tbl 
                           ORDER BY time
                           DESC LIMIT 5)
```