# Displaying content but not the latest one

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have these codes to display content on my website.

Index.php

```
$rest = new rest;
$list = $rest->fetch_all();

<?php foreach ($rest->fetch_all() as $rest) { ?>
<br>
<a href="episode.php?id=<?php echo $rest['cast_id']; ?>">
#<?php echo $rest['cast_id']; ?>: <?php echo $rest['cast_title']; ?>
<br>
<font size="2" color="red">
<?php echo $rest['cast_about']; ?></font></a><br>
<br><div class="divider"> </div><br>

<?php } ?>
```

And include.php

> class rest {
>       public function fetch_all(){
>           global $pdo;
>
> ```
>     $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM podcast ORDER BY cast_id DESC");
>     $query->execute();
>
>     return $query->fetchAll();
> } }
> ```

Please can someone tell me how I can get this to show results but not the latest result?

All fields are numbered using an ID tag in mysql.

On my site I have the latest entry listed above this list so I do not require the latest one appearing here.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: `LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 10` in the end of query will ignore 10 top rows. Try it. (Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows))

Comment: Nope. Just displays no results.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM podcast ORDER BY cast_id DESC LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to discard the row in the application. You can do it in SQL by using a calculated limit. Calculate it as `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM podcast) - 1`.

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM podcast
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM podcast
ORDER BY cast_id ASC
```

Excluding the last row.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) or [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) depending on your query sorting as shown bellow:

Assuming the latest result is the first raw on your query result.

```
$rest = new rest;
$list = $rest->fetch_all();
$latest = array_shift($list);

<?php foreach ($list as $rest) { ?>
<br>
<a href="episode.php?id=<?php echo $rest['cast_id']; ?>">
#<?php echo $rest['cast_id']; ?>: <?php echo $rest['cast_title']; ?>
<br>
<font size="2" color="red">
<?php echo $rest['cast_about']; ?></font></a><br>
<br><div class="divider"> </div><br>

<?php } ?>
```

If it's the last raw that you need to hide, then use array_pop

Comment: Yeah, that is better idea. +1

Comment: Adding $latest = array_pop($list); displays no change for me.

Comment: I've updated the code. You should use array_shift instead, see edited code above