# fetching all the salary from the 2nd highest with limit

Tags: mysql

i found using order by with limit to fetch 2nd highest salary from database.may be it can enhance database performance when fetching from large number, rather using sub-query.i want to know how to fetch all the salary starting from 2nd highest salary. i have created table like & db name = one

```
id                   salary
1                    50
2                    20
3                    70
4                    40
5                    85
```

now to find only the 2nd highest salary

```
select salary from one order by salary desc limit 1,1
```

to find the salary of 2nd and 3rd and 4th

```
select salary from one order by salary desc limit 2,1
```

how to fetch all the salary starting from 2nd highest without knowing the 2nd limit value.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a really, really big value:

```
select salary
from one
order by salary desc
limit 99999999 offset 1;
```

Alternatively, you could calculate it:

```
select salary
from one
where salary < (select min(salary) from one)
```

Both these will run faster with an index on `one(salary)`.

And, there is a subtle difference between the two.  The first will return the second salary, even if equal to the highest salary.  The second version will return the second highest salary, regardless of duplicates.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) :(

Comment: @black . . . Because I always seem to get the arguments backwards when using offset.  Arrgh.  I just made it explicit  using the keyword `offset` rather than the implicitly with the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use query as

```
select salary from one
where salary > (select min(salary) from one)
```

Comment: not fetching from 2nd highest. omitting the last value. can we use limit only?

Answer (score 0):

its working fine with

```
select salary from one
where salary < (select max(salary) from one)
```

but how to use limit only?

Answer (score 0):

Use the offset feature of mysql:

Since you want to select salaries from 2nd highest to the end, you can use following query:

```
select salary from one order by salary desc limit 18446744073709551615 offset 1
```

PS: 18446744073709551615 = 2^64-1 (Refer to [Mysql Offset Infinite rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271650/2036529))