# Laravel Eloquent skip n, take all?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, offset

I've noticed that in Laravel when chaining a `skip()` you must also use `take()` as well. I want to skip the first n rows but take the rest. The take method only allows integers how can I do this without resorting to some hacky trick such as specifying a large number for take?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Basically, with every OFFSET, a LIMIT must be supplied for mysql to work. Therefore, there is no way to do this without sepcifying a limit. We need some php mojo to work here.

Let's say we have an Eloquent Class named `Attendance`. Here's what should work:

```
//Getting count
$count = Attendance::count();
$skip = 5;
$limit = $count - $skip; // the limit
$collection = Attendance::skip($skip)->take($limit)->get();
```

Comment: I agree. Interesting read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows

Answer (score 9):

If you're using MySQL and you don't want to have 2 queries to get the max rows, you may use the PHP maximum INT value as `take()` parameter e.g. `take(PHP_INT_MAX)`.

It's because Laravel Query Grammar [casts the limit to integer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L679). So you can't use a larger number than that.

From [MySQL documentation on LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#id4651990):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.

For example:

```
\App\User::skip(10)->take(PHP_INT_MAX)->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a good answer, because you're forcing to do two queries, the right way will be:

```
$collection = Attendance::skip($skip)->take($limit)->get();
$collection.shift();
```

You can see more about collections [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections)

Comment: Cannot understand why? and no define the $limit first?

Comment: Basically calling count() first will trigger a count query, that's not what you want, you only want take a number and skip the first, this translate to SQL to LIMIT <skip>, <take>