# Laravel Eloquent limit and offset

Tags: laravel, eloquent, limit, offset

This is mine

```
    $art = Article::where('id',$article)->firstOrFail();
    $products = $art->products;
```

I just wanna take a limit 'product'
This is wrong way

```
   $products = $art->products->offset($offset*$limit)->take($limit)->get();
```

Please give me a hand!

Thanks!

Comment: this would help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457249/laravel-eloquent-skip-n-take-all

Comment: @SangTrần Just use `products()` instead of `products`. And it'll work.

Comment: As Doan Tran mentioned, you should be calling those methods on the builder, not a collection. Collections do not have a method `skip`.

Comment: Please add what version of Laravel you are using. There are many of them.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

```
skip = OFFSET
$products = $art->products->skip(0)->take(10)->get(); //get first 10 rows
$products = $art->products->skip(10)->take(10)->get(); //get next 10 rows
```

From laravel doc 5.2 https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

> **skip / take**
>
> To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a
>   given number of results in the query (OFFSET), you may use the skip
>   and take methods:
>
> `$users = DB::table('users')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();`

In **laravel 5.3** you can write (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
$products = $art->products->offset(0)->limit(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 36):

#### Quick:

Laravel has a fast pagination method, paginate, which only needs to pass in the number of data displayed per page.

```php
//use the paginate
Book::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(8);
```

#### how to customize paging:

you can use these method: `offset`，`limit` ,`skip`，`take`

- offset，limit : where does the offset setting start, limiting the amount of data to be queried
- skip，take: skip skips a few pieces of data and takes a lot of data

for example:

```php
Model::offset(0)->limit(10)->get();

Model::skip(3)->take(3)->get()；


//i use it in my project, work fine ~

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function getList(Request $request) {

        $page = $request->has('page') ? $request->get('page') : 1;
        $limit = $request->has('limit') ? $request->get('limit') : 10;

        $books = Book::where('status', 0)->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit)->get()->toArray();

        return $this->getResponse($books, count($books));
    }
}
```

Comment: This will return empty for pages with rows less than the limit, since its offsetting beyond the scope.

Answer (score 18):

laravel have own function `skip` for `offset` and `take` for `limit`. just like below example of laravel query :-

```
Article::where([['user_id','=',auth()->user()->id]])
                ->where([['title','LIKE',"%".$text_val."%"]])
                ->orderBy('id','DESC')
                ->skip(0)
                ->take(2)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `skip` and `take` functions as below:

```
$products = $art->products->skip($offset*$limit)->take($limit)->get();
```

// `skip` should be passed param as integer value to skip the records and starting index

// `take` gets an integer value to get the no. of records after starting index defined by `skip`

**EDIT**

Sorry. I was misunderstood with your question. If you want something like pagination the `forPage` method will work for you. forPage method works for collections.

[REf : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-forpage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-forpage)

**e.g**

```
$products = $art->products->forPage($page,$limit);
```

Comment: Collections don't have a `skip` method.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this

`$products = $art->products->take($limit)->skip($offset)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$products = Article::orderBy('id', 'asc')->limit($limit)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
return Article::where('id',$article)->with(['products'=>function($products, $offset, $limit) {
    return $products->offset($offset*$limit)->limit($limit);
}])
```

Comment: Thanks, Nisam but it not work.
in my DB, an article has many products through 'article_product' table. I can show all products (e.g which is related with article_id =1 )

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
$art = Article::where('id',$article)->firstOrFail();

$products = $art->products->take($limit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

$chunk = $collection->forPage(2, 3);

$chunk->all();
```

Answer (score -2):

Laravel 5.1< (current v 9)

```
$art->products->skip($offset)->take($limit)->all();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-take