# How to get limited data to paginating

Tags: php

```
    $rowsPerPage = 50;
    $num = 1;
    $offsets = ($num - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

    $data['trans'] = Transaction::withoutBranch()
    ->select('id', 'amount')
    ->where('payment_date', '>=', '2019-06-07')
    ->limit($offsets)
    ->get();
```

I'm using Laravel 4.2 to do the planning. I trying to get the data from data with 50 on the first page then the second page will get another new 50 data.

I did try the code but it still gets all of the data from the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent limit and offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643192/laravel-eloquent-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following:

```
$data['trans'] = Transaction::withoutBranch()
    ->select('id', 'amount')
    ->where('payment_date', '>=', '2019-06-07')
    ->limit($rowsPerPage)
    ->offset($offsets)
    ->get();
```