# Limit to only one value in my drop-down list

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu

I have a form `payments` with 4 fields -> `date_paying, type_sitting, number_seance, fk_student`.

[image]

In my form `trainings` I have 3 fields -> `date_sitting, fk_payment, fk_student`.

[image]

My problem is that when I want to add a recording, I retrieve 2 times the same value in my drop down list.

[image]

I really want to keep only an item

In my create.blade(trainings) I have this:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('fk_payment') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
   <label for="company-content">Payment </label>
     <select name="fk_payment" id="fk_payment" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('fk_payment')}}"/>
        <option value="">Choice Payment</option>
           @foreach($payments as $payment)
             <option value="{{$payment->id}}" {{ old('fk_payment') == $payment->id ?  'selected' : '' }} >
             {{$payment->type_sitting}}
             </option>
           @endforeach
     {!! $errors->first('fk_payment', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
  </select>
```

Here is my Controller **Training**

```
class TrainingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


    public function index()
    {
        $trainings = Training::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.trainings.index', compact('trainings'));
                with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1) *5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   

        $payments = Payment::all();
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('admin.trainings.create', compact('payments', 'students','trainings'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_sitting' => 'required',
                'fk_payment' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required'


        ]);


       $exists = Training::where('date_sitting', $request->get('date_sitting'))->where('fk_payment', $request->get('fk_payment'))->where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->count();

       if (!$exists){


        //$payment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();

        $payment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();

        if(!isset($payment)){ 
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('error', 'No Payment, no training for you!');
        }
        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }
    }


    }
```

Controller **Payment**

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $payments = Payment::oldest()->paginate(5);
        return view('admin.payments.index', compact('payments'));
                with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1) *5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   
        $students = Student::all();
        return view('admin.payments.create', compact('students', 'payments'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_payment' => 'required',
                'type_sitting' => 'required',
                'number_seance' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required'

        ]);

       $exists = Payment::where('date_payment', $request->get('date_payment'))->where('type_sitting', $request->get('type_sitting'))->where('number_seance', $request->get('number_seance'))->where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->count();



       if (!$exists){
            Payment::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('payments.index')
                ->with('error', 'doublon');

        }   

    }
```

Model - **Payment**

```
class Payment extends Model
{
    //
    protected  $fillable = ['date_payment', 'type_sitting', 'number_seance',  'fk_student'];

    protected $dates = ['date_payment'];

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }

    public function trainings(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Training', 'fk_payment');
    }
}
```

Model - **Training**

```
class Training extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['date_sitting',  'fk_payment', 'fk_student',];
    protected $dates = ['date_sitting'];

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }

    public function payments(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Payment', 'fk_payment');
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: can you `dd($payements)` in your controller and post the result?

Answer (score 0):

Change your this specific blade:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('fk_payment') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
   <label for="company-content">Payment </label>
     <select name="fk_payment" id="fk_payment" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('fk_payment')}}"/>
        <option value="">Choice Payment</option>
           @foreach($payments as $payment)
               @php
                    $training = App\Training::where('fk_payment', $payment->fk_payment)->first();
               @endphp

             <option value="{{$payment->id}}" {{ old('fk_payment') == $payment->id ?  'selected' : '' }} >
             {{  $training->type_sitting )}}
             </option>
           @endforeach
     {!! $errors->first('fk_payment', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
  </select>
```

[See more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643192/laravel-eloquent-limit-and-offset)

Comment: Thank you I must to do the modification here? `$payment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();` Where put the `->take()`

Comment: yeah specify the number like for example you want one then `->take(1)`

Comment: Sadly, I always have the even problem. I several have items in my dropdownlist.

Comment: I want to limit my dropdownlist to an item but it's a foreign key. I have a screenshot in my first message 3rd image. I think it's impossible?

Comment: @user11124425 hmm.. can you put your full codes of your controller. I think there must be something in there that can help solve this problem.

Comment: I have edited my first message. For information it's the function store().

Comment: what foreign key specifically you want to limit?

Comment: `fk_payment -> field -> type_sitting` with the value `practice`

Comment: @user11124425 very last one, important. can you show the two model (**Payment Model**, **Foreign Model**. just copy paste it.

Comment: @user11124425 I think `$payment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
                    ->take(1)
                    ->get();` is the solution, but can you explain me what is wrong with this

Comment: It doesn't works... I think it's impossible. I have seeked for 2 days hahahha

Comment: I have a problem de syntax `"syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' ` I have edited my first message with a screenshot...

Comment: @user11124425 I think I must sleep now, its already 4am here. maybe you should wait for me tomorrow or the answer from others ^^

Comment: No worries, good night soon I hope. Thank you again for your help.