# Laravel limit query param results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a query which filters films based upon the input by the user, i am needing to add a `limit` as a query parameter so it limits the amount of films that are returned, how do i add this in, i am new to writing eloquent queries.

**query**

```
$films = Film
::when($request->input('first'), function ($query, $first) {
    $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($first) {
        $query->where('first', $main);
    });
})
->when($request->input('second'), function ($query, $second) {
    $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($second) {
        $query->where('second', $second );
    });
})
->when($request->input('age'), function ($query, $age) {
    $query->whereHas('ageRatings', function ($query) use ($age) {
        $query->where('age', $age);
    });
})
->when($request->input('country'), function ($query, $country) {
    $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($country) {
        $query->where('country', $country);
    });
})
->when($request->input('city'), function ($query, $city) {
    $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($city) {
        $query->where('city', $city);
    });
})
->get();
```

Comment: don't you use ->limit(5) ? like bfore ->limit(5)->get() ?

Comment: Use `->take(10) -> get...` See other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643192/laravel-eloquent-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$query->limit(5)` or `$query->take(5)`.

If you want to skip the first 5 results, use `$query->skip(5)`

If you want to add pagination, you can use `$query->paginate(5)`

See More: [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries)

Comment: thanks will the url look like this then `/films?limit=5`

Comment: This has nothing to do with urls. You need to update your url or get the value from the url manually

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of these method

the **Limit** method

```
$limit = 10;
$films = Film
::when($request->input('first'), function ($query, $first) {
    $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($first) {
        $query->where('first', $first);
    });
})
->when($request->input('second'), function ($query, $second) {
    $query->whereHas(‘options', function ($query) use ($second) {
        $query->where('second', $second);
    });
})
->when($request->input('age'), function ($query, $age) {
    $query->whereHas('ageRatings', function ($query) use ($age) {
        $query->where('age', $age);
    });
})
->when($request->input('country'), function ($query, $country) {
    $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($country) {
        $query->where('country', $country);
    });
})
->when($request->input('city'), function ($query, $city) {
    $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($city) {
        $query->where('city', $city);
    });
})
->limit($limit)
->get();
```

the **Take** method

```
$limit = 10;
    $films = Film
    ::when($request->input('first'), function ($query, $first) {
        $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($first) {
            $query->where('first', $first);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('second'), function ($query, $second) {
        $query->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($second) {
            $query->where('second', $second);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('age'), function ($query, $age) {
        $query->whereHas('ageRatings', function ($query) use ($age) {
            $query->where('age', $age);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('country'), function ($query, $country) {
        $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($country) {
            $query->where('country', $country);
        });
    })
    ->when($request->input('city'), function ($query, $city) {
        $query->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($city) {
            $query->where('city', $city);
        });
    })
    ->take($limit)
    ->get();
```

Comment: thanks will the url look like this then `/films?limit=10`

Comment: `get the value of limit in url` do you mean this solution you provided will return the above url or am i needing to get something else

Comment: no it does not, you have to get first the value of limit in your url and initialize it to a variable before you execute the query

Comment: btw there are two options on how you can get the value of limit you want to pass, just visit this article https://www.5balloons.info/how-to-get-url-parameters-into-controller-laravel/