# How to transform this raw SQL query into Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

This raw SQL query is returning the expected result on my SQL console. Would you please help me to transform it into a Laravel Eloquent query?

```
SELECT * FROM `my_services` 
    WHERE `user_id` = 1 and `financial_year` = '2021-2022' 
    AND (service_type = 'Return' OR service_type = 'Correction Return') 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

I have tried to implement it like the following.

```
MyService::where([
    'user_id' => $user->id, 
    'financial_year' => $request->financial_year,
    'financial_year' => '2021-2022'
])
->orWhere(['service_type' => 'Return'])
->orWhere(['service_type' => 'Correction Return'])
->orderBy("id", "desc")
->offset(1)
->limit(1)
->get();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643192/laravel-eloquent-limit-and-offset

Comment: MyService::where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->where('financial_year', $request->financial_year)
                ->where(function($q) {
                    $q->orWhereIn('service_type', ['Return', 'Correction Return']);
                })->orderBy("id", "desc")->skip(1)->take(1)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
MyService::where('user_id', 1)->where('financial_year', '2021-2022')->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('service_type', 'Return')->orWhere('service_type', 'Correction Return');
})->limit(1)->offset(1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: financial_year has a single value there are no multiple years. so can  you correct me with a single value I think it should be `->where('financial_year', '2021-2022')`

Comment: @ayat I've updated the query. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset

Use `->skip(1)` or `->offset(1)` for offset

Use `->take(1)` or `->limit(1)` to limit count of returned results