# Can i use offset (skip) with GroupBy?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Below is my query, and i have added some description what i want.

```
$recommendedByVideoId = RecommendedVideo::selectRaw('video_id,id')
                ->orderBy('played_count', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                ->get()
                ->skip(3)
                ->take(2)
                ->groupBy('video_id')
```

Below is my query result :

```
        [video_id_1] => [record1, record2, record3, record4, record5],
        [video_id_2] => [record1, record2, record3, record4, record5],
        [video_id_3] => [record1, record2, record3, record4, record5],
        [video_id_4] => [record1, record2, record3, record4, record5],
        [video_id_5] => [record1, record2, record3, record4, record5, record6, record7],
```

Expected Result should be something like:

```
        [video_id_1] => [record4, record5],
        [video_id_2] => [record4, record5],
        [video_id_3] => [record4, record5],
        [video_id_4] => [record4, record5],
        [video_id_5] => [record4, record5],
```

Please help me to write out query, that skip records from inner collection not from outer.

Thanks.

Comment: You need either `ROW_NUMBER` or user variables to do this query.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen let me try that, and thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

here its already answered in statckoverflow [skip frist row and take the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457249/laravel-eloquent-skip-n-take-all)

so for using  this, you have to use `take` method with `skip` because with offset you give number right.

**So first get the `count` how many rows you have in the database.**

`$count = Model::count()`

**Then `$skip = 3`
find `limit` you provide to `take` method**
`$limit = $count - $skip`
**And Now heres you final query**

```
Model::skip($skip)->take($limit)->get();
```

you can use it with groupBy too

and if you don't want to change your query then get all data without `skip` or `take`
and use collection method `except`

`$data = $dataFromDataBase->except([0,1,2]);`

it will automatically remove given keys from your data

Comment: you can group it too

Comment: or you can you `except` method for skip first rows like `$data = $collection->except([0,1,2]);`