# How to select rows above #

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to setup a query that only selects from a row number and upwards from it. I've tried to use the `LIMIT` method in this way:

```
SELECT name FROM names LIMIT 1500, *
```

Which I expected to select from **row number 1500** till the table's rows ended, but got a MySQL error instead.

I then tried to use a conditional for the ID of the rows like so:

```
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id >= 1500
```

Which gave unpredictable behavior since there are rows that get deleted, so it's not taking the real row numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Offset Infinite rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think offset will do what you want.  Unfortunately, MySQL requires a `LIMIT` value, but you can just put in a ridiculous number:

```
SELECT name
FROM names 
OFFSET 1499
LIMIT 999999999;
```

Comment: Although a bit messy, it works perfectly. Thanks for the quick solution. :D

Answer (score 1):

you could use a subquery

```
select name 
from names 
where id > (
    select max(id) 
    from names 
    order by names  
    limit 1500 
)
```