# Group all rows after nth row together

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have the current table:

```
+----------+-------+
| salesman | sales |
+----------+-------+
|        1 |   142 |
|        2 |   120 |
|        3 |   176 |
|        4 |   140 |
|        5 |   113 |
|        6 |   137 |
|        7 |   152 |
+----------+-------+
```

I would like to make a query to retrieve the 3 top salesman, and an "Other" column, that would be the sum of everyone else. The expected output would be:

```
+----------+-------+
| salesman | sales |
+----------+-------+
| 3        |   176 |
| 7        |   152 |
| 1        |   142 |
| Others   |   510 |
+----------+-------+
```

I am using MySQL, and I am experienced about it, but i can't imagine a way of doing this kind of `GROUP BY`.

A tried `UNION` with 2 `SELECT`, one for the top 3 salesman and another select for the "Others", but I couldn't figure a way of excluding the top 3 from the 2nd `SELECT`

Comment: Why don't you share that attempt with us, thus demonstrating a valid attempt at solving your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by `LEFT JOIN`ing your table to a list of the top 3 salesmen, and then grouping on the `COALESCE`d salesman number from the top 3 table (which will be `NULL` if the salesman is not in the top 3).

```
SELECT COALESCE(top.sman, 'Others') AS saleman,
       SUM(sales) AS sales
FROM test
LEFT JOIN (SELECT salesman AS sman
           FROM test
           ORDER BY sales DESC
           LIMIT 3) top ON top.sman = test.salesman
GROUP BY saleman
ORDER BY saleman = 'Others', sales DESC
```

Output:

```
saleman sales
3       176
7       152
1       142
Others  510
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2B4sEKisE8hL5dn3RTbcSM/0)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Kudos for beeing in a single select and very simple, yet, creative

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp thanks. It's not really a single select though as there is the derived table as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using `UNION`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, `OFFSET` AND `GROUP BY` statements you should do the trick:

```
SELECT salesman, sales 
FROM t 
ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 3
UNION
SELECT 'Others', SUM(sales) 
FROM (SELECT salesman, sales 
      FROM t 
      ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 3, 18446744073709551615) AS tt;
```

The big number at the end is the way to apply limit until the end of the table, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/271650/1049569)

Answer (score 2):

This is a pain in MySQL:

```
(select salesman, count(*) as cnt
 from t
 group by salesman
 order by count(*), salesman
 limit 3
) union all
(select 'Others', count(*)
 from t left join
      (select salesman, count(*) as cnt
       from t
       group by salesman
       order by count(*)
       limit 3
      ) t3
      on t3.salesman = t.salesman
 where t3.salesman is null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the fastest one if appropriate indexes are present[:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=996383cd00b0a1313151a2289d3ac695)

```
(
    SELECT salesman, sales
    FROM t
    ORDER BY sales DESC
    LIMIT 3
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT 'Other', SUM(sales) - (
        SELECT SUM(sales)
        FROM (
            SELECT sales
            FROM t
            ORDER BY sales DESC
            LIMIT 3
        ) AS top3
    )
    FROM t
)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN salesman = 'Other' THEN NULL ELSE sales END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select salesman,sales from tablename a where a.salesman in (3,7,1) 
union all
select 'others' as others,sum(a.sales) as sum_of_others from tablename a where 
a.salesman not in (3,7,1) group by others;
```

check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73GjFXL3KsZsYnN26g3rS2/0

Comment: I hope in the second select, it should be `select 'Others' as salesman,`

Comment: Use no hard-coded id's... _top 3 salesman_ and _excluding the top 3_...