# selecting all rows except top row using offset in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use offset clause to get all rows except the first row. I am using query like

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY SALARY OFFSET 1;
```

But this is not working in MySQL. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: In SQL server it would be `offset 1 rows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly in MySQL OFFSET only works together with the LIMIT clause. So you need to use

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY SALARY LIMIT 18446744073709551615 OFFSET 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY SALARY LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;
```

I have chosen that limit number from a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 can use a window function to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY) AS rownum
  FROM EMPLOYEES
) AS t
WHERE rownum > 1
ORDER BY SALARY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LIMIT in addition to OFFSET

`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY SALARY LIMIT 9999 OFFSET 1;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).